# Get-PnPSiteTemplate: Customizing 'config.json' schema to provision PnP Site template

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Based on the article Configuring the PnP Provisioning Engine, I was trying to configure the config.json schema so that I could extract a particular set of content types, lists and fields into my template.

Two things: First I am unable to define specific content types that I want to extract into the template and second thing is I don't see a structure to include only a specific set of Fields in my template.
Is there a way that we can modify these configurations in the config.json that can be used with Get-PnPSiteTemplate?

```
type {
"$schema":"https://aka.ms/sppnp-extract-configuration-schema",
"persistAssetFiles": true,
"handlers": [
"Lists",
"ContentTypes",
"Fields"
],
"lists": {
"lists": [
{
"title": "My Test List"
}
}
]
},
"contentTypes": {
"groups": [
"Content Type A"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can modify the configurations in the `config.json` as long as the modifications are valid & supported by the official schema given here:

[PnP Provisioning Engine Extraction Schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/pnp/provisioning/201910/extract-configuration.schema.json)

This schema is updated regularly whenever any new feature is added to PnP Provisioning Engine.

For more details, check this Microsoft official documentation: [Configuring the PnP Provisioning Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/configuring-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)

Comment: OH I see! I must say that the schema doesn't support defining content types & felds explicitly within the json config file yet. Is there an alternate way that we could utilise PnP Powershell to extract specific content types and lists in the template that can be applied to another sharepoint site?